# How to set Artifact Path at runtime

Tags: java, teamcity

I'm developing build runner plugin for Teamcity. I want to publish the artifact to Teamcity server when the build is done.

However, I only find where to set Artifact Path on server before the build is started. The build runner will generate artifact in a random file folder, I can only get the file folder when the build is running.

Here comes question, how to set Artifact Path when the build is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity artifacts can be published via a [service message](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-artPublishingPublishingArtifactswhiletheBuildisStillinProgress). This is available for any build script or build tool.

An agent plugin can also publish artifacts via a call to [ArtifactsWatcher.addNewArtifactsPath](http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/current/jetbrains/buildServer/agent/artifacts/ArtifactsWatcher.html#addNewArtifactsPath(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will have a try later and give you feedback after that

Comment: By your answer, I figured out how to publish artifact dynamically. Thanks a lot. ^_^